# Box2D - How to speed up acceleration

Tags: box2d, physics, game-physics

I have a body that I am applying a force to every step. However, it takes a significant amount of time for it to speed up, which I do not want. Is there some value I can adjust to help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember Newton's Second Law from high school physics

> F = m * a

Where F is force, m is mass, and a is acceleration. Your goal is to increase acceleration, so you rearrange the formula to:

> a = F / m

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

- [Apply](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#ab3ede408c7f21b9828119b6b88f268ea) a larger force (making F bigger)
- Decrease the [density](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/structb2_fixture_def.html#a6e27d733789a35aa689af2b30a1de0ff) of the fixture (it is set to 1.0 by default). If you decrease the density but hold the shape type and shape dimensions fixed, the mass must decrease as a result. This will also increase acceleration.

Finally, if you want to restrict the maximum speed you need to play with the [linear damping](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#a909f9753ad700f70282a56e00bc182a5) of the body (the default is 0). Changing the linear damping is like changing the drag coefficient of the body. Lower values are for sleek and streamlined objects like bullets. Higher linear damping values are for really rough and angular objects like [shuttlecocks](https://www.google.ca/search?q=shuttlecock&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=lTxEUqXOMoXFrQGvyIDgAw&ved=0CD8QsAQ&biw=1855&bih=968&dpr=1).

So if you want to have an object speed up very quickly when the force is applied apply a larger force and/or reduce the fixture's density. If you want to set/decrease the max speed of the object, increase the linear damping.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what exactly you are looking for. Your question isn't clear on what you want to implement the acceleration upon.If you could, perhaps give us a snippet of your code, then maybe we'll have some proper understanding on what exactly you want to achieve. I am assuming you want to give acceleration to an object that increases with time and you want to restrain it after a certain velocity. If you need some basics on how to manipulate or adjust an object's speed or velocity. I suggest you have a look at this [LINK](http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/) and go through it thoroughly and try implementing it in your application...